# Display part of search result (FTS in Sql)

Tags: sql-server, substring, full-text-search

I have a table with multi-line Persian contents in SQL Server 2019 that are taken from ckeditor on the site (my site language is ASP.NET C#).
I want to search in this table with FTS, but not display the search results in full but only a part of the content of each result cell that includes phrase (for example, 100 characters or 10 words) that the phrase Searched first or in the middle of it. How is this possible?

in a little English example  if this phrase is in a cell of the table:

> The university has a lot of student. One of them is Zahra. She studies computer science and like it.

I want when search for

> Zahra

(with FTS) the result should be displayed as:

> ... One of them is Zahra. She studies computer science...

I wanted to use substring but in CONTAIN in FTS only returns results with the exact phrase searched, not close phrase.

Comment: What does "close phrase" mean? Have you looked at other FTS functions, such as `SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/semanticsimilaritydetailstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Mean similar to the phrase. 

Comment: And what about using `CONTAINSTABLE` with a `NEAR` or `FORMSOF` condition